# POSTGRES : Data import

Tags: postgresql, import, jsonb

DB Version : 13.x

1. Source table schema\

   ```sql
   CREATE TABLE mig_bus_data
          mig_id  SERIAL,
          mig_data JSONB
   ```
2. Target table schema\

   ```
   CREATE TABLE BUSINESS
       id   UNIQUE SERIAL,
      data1  <TYPEx>,
      data2  <TYPEy>,
      .
      .
   ```
3. All indexes on target table dropped
4. Data being imported in blocks of 100 records in parallel using
   Process 1

   ```
    CURSOR 
    select mig_data from mig_bus_data LIMIT 100  OFFSET 0
   ```

   Process 2

   ```
     CURSOR 
     select mig_data from mig_bus_data LIMIT 100  OFFSET 100
   .
   .
   ```

Notes :

1. After dropping indexes and doing  step 4, there is no significant performance gain.

Any pointer to increase speed would help.

Comment: The imported data model is that of  TREE.  REGIONS divide in to ZONES and LOCATIONS within zones.

Comment: "Any pointer to increase speed" -- don't do any of that nonsense and simply `INSERT ... SELECT...`.

Answer (score 0):

> 4. Data being imported in blocks of 100 records in parallel using

```
  select mig_data from mig_bus_data LIMIT 100  OFFSET 100
```

I can't imagine why you would want to do that.
We have no evidence that you benched it and observed a speedup.
The question suggests that you're seeing dreadfully slow throughput
with such batching, as expected.

For a web page it can make sense to paginate and issue LIMIT x OFFSET y queries.
But for data migration? That's crazy.

Just SELECT * to tablescan the source relation.
That's the fastest you can drag those rows off the disk.

And INSERT into the destination table.
COMMIT at the end.

If you're keen to stick with the current code,
at least increase the batch size to something
that will take more than moment to complete,
perhaps 10,000 rows at a time.

---

Perhaps slow WAN connectivity for a database TCP connection
is behind the observed slowness.
Decouple the pieces if you want to observe and diagnose the details.

Locally serialize source rows out to the filesystem, perhaps as a *.csv file.
Measure number of rows, divided by elapsed time, to find app level throughput.

Transfer the file to the destination DB server.
Again measure, to find the network bandwidth.

Locally read the CSV, INSERTing rows into destination table.
See whether writing throughput was much lower than the reading throughput.

Identify which one was the bottleneck stage.
Invest in resources to improve the bottleneck.